# Deep linking in React native

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, deep-linking

Hi all i am using deep linking for my app, onclick of link if app is installed app is opening using below code.
in androidmanifest.xml i have added this intent filter code

```
     <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data
      android:scheme="vbccustomer"
      android:host="planrenewal" />
  </intent-filter>
```

in app.js added this code:
const prefix = 'vbccustomer://'; // replace with your custom scheme

```
export default function App() {
  const [appState, setAppState] = useState(AppState.currentState);
  const navigationRef = useRef();

  const linking = {
    prefixes: [prefix],
  };

  const handleDeepLink = async({url}) => {
    // Handle the deep link URL here
    const route = url.replace(prefix, '');
    const isAppInstalled = await Linking.canOpenURL(url);

    if (isAppInstalled) {
      // Use navigationRef to access the navigation prop
      if (navigationRef.current && route === 'planrenewal') {
        navigationRef.current.navigate('PlanRenewal');
      } else {
        navigationRef.current.navigate('Splashscreen');
      }
    } else {
      // Redirect to Play Store or alternative action
      Linking.openURL('playstore link');
    }
    // Use navigationRef to access the navigation prop
    // if (navigationRef.current) {
    //   navigationRef.current.navigate(route);
    // }
  
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    // Add event listener for deep links
    Linking.addEventListener('url', handleDeepLink);

    // Clean up the event listener
    return () => {
      Linking.removeEventListener('url', handleDeepLink);
    };
  }, []);
  useEffect(() => {
    const handleAppStateChange = (nextAppState) => {
      if (appState.match(/inactive|background/) && nextAppState === 'active') {
        // Check app installation when app comes to the foreground
        checkAppInstallation();
      }
      setAppState(nextAppState);
    };

    AppState.addEventListener('change', handleAppStateChange);

    return () => {
      AppState.removeEventListener('change', handleAppStateChange);
    };
  }, [appState]);

  const checkAppInstallation = async () => {
    const isAppInstalled = await Linking.canOpenURL(prefix);

    if (!isAppInstalled) {
      // Redirect to Play Store or alternative action
      Linking.openURL('playstore link');
    }
  }
return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <PersistGate persistor={persistor}>
        <NavigationContainer linking={linking} ref={navigationRef}>
          <MainNavigator />
          <Toast position="top" visibilityTime={5000} />
        </NavigationContainer>
      </PersistGate>
    </Provider>
  );
}
```

If app is not installed i need to redirect to playstore, which is not happening from this code.
link using to click on to open the app is
`<a href="vbccustomer://planrenewal">Click here to renew your plan</a>`

I have been stuck on redirecting to playstore if app is not installed, Do i need to chnage the link which i am using for click